# Is there a way to redirect a domain (maybe even a url) from firefox to chrome and vice versa?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, browser, redirection

I've noticed that google apps are a bit faster in chrome. So what I'd like to do is open *both* Firefox and Chrome--on the same computer--and use Chrome to do the Google stuff and Firefox to do most other things. Problem is I sometimes try to use one of google's pervasive apps or another.. Bonus if the browser you're forwarding **from** does not change the page it's on when the redirect happens.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood something, but if you plan to have both Firefox and Chrome open, wouldn't whatever slight speed benefit evaporate anyway?

Comment: @DigitalDracula No. My PC is beefy enough to handle both applications optimally. It is no detriment to page load speed, etc, which is where your bottleneck is.